# Is there a way to union multiple nodes based on ID or Text when using Kendo tree view?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have 3 different object / node as below, and I am trying to form the finalObj / node which is the union (unique tree list) of the 3 nodes..

Is there a method in tree view with which I can union 3 objects (nodes)  based on text or id ?

```
First node: 

 [ { text: "TreeRoot", items: [
                                { text: "Subgroup1" },
                                { text: "Subgroup2" }   
                            ]}]

Second Node:
                 [ { text: "TreeRoot", items: [
                            { text: "Subgroup3" }   
                        ]}]


Third node:
                 [{ text: "Subgroup3",
                        items: [ {
                                text: "subgroup5",
                                items: [ {
                                        text: "subgroup6",
                                        items: [ {
                                                text: "subgroup7",
                                                items: [ {
                                                        text: "subgroup8"
                                                    }]
                                            }] }] 
                            }]}]



Final expected node (after merging):

                var finalObj= [ { text: "TreeRoot", items: [
                            { text: "Subgroup1" },
                            { text: "Subgroup2" },
                            { text: "Subgroup3",
                                items: [ {
                                        text: "subgroup5",
                                        items: [ {
                                                text: "subgroup6",
                                                items: [ {
                                                        text: "subgroup7",
                                                        items: [ {
                                                                text: "subgroup8"
                                                            }]
                                                    }] }] 
                                    }]}]}]
```

EDIT:

The below solution doesnt work for other type of nodes..

For EX:

```
   var node1 = [
                    { text   : "TreeRoot",
                        id:0,
                        items: [
                            { text: "Subgroup1",id:1 },
                            { text: "Subgroup2", id:2}
                        ]
                    }
                ];

            var node2 = [
                {
                    text : "TreeRoot",
                    id:0,
                    items: [
                        { text: "Subgroup3" ,
                        id:3}
                    ]
                }
            ];


            var node3 = [
                {
                    text : "TreeRoot",
                     id:0,
                    items: [
                        {
                            text : "Subgroup2",
                            id:2,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    text : "subgroup6",
                                    id:6,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            text : "subgroup7",
                                            id:7,
                                            items: [
                                                {
                                                    text: "subgroup8",
                                                    id:8
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

For above example I should see just tree root initially. When expanded I should see just subgroup1,2,3... and when subgroup2 is expanded I should be able to see subgroup6,7,8.

I need unique parent and child nodes.. If I use the above structure, I get 2 child node named- Subgroup3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you tag it as Kendo-UI it is actually a programming problem since there is no KendoUI interface for solving (I know that you want to use it for merging `treeview` nodes) it *but* it is not very hard solving it using recursion.

This are basically your three nodes:

```
var node1 = [
    { text   : "TreeRoot",
        items: [
            { text: "Subgroup1" },
            { text: "Subgroup2" }
        ]
    }
];

var node2 = [
    {
        text : "TreeRoot",
        items: [
            { text: "Subgroup3" }
        ]
    }
];


var node3 = [
    {
        text : "Subgroup3",
        items: [
            {
                text : "subgroup5",
                items: [
                    {
                        text : "subgroup6",
                        items: [
                            {
                                text : "subgroup7",
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        text: "subgroup8"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

You can merge it using the following function:

```
function merge(node1, node2) {
    if (node2 !== null) {
        if (node1.text === node2.text) {
            node1.items = node1.items || [];
            $.each(node2.items, function (idx2, elem2) {
                var found = false;
                // Check that elem does not exist on node1
                $.each(node1.items, function (idx1, elem1) {
                    if (!found && elem1.text === elem2.text) {
                        found = true;
                        merge(elem1, elem2);
                    }
                });
                if (!found) {
                    node1.items.push(elem2);
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (node1.items) {
                $.each(node1.items, function (idx, item) {
                    merge(item, node2);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That merges two nodes in the first one.

And you should invoke it like this:

```
merge(node1[0], node2[0]);
merge(node1[0], node3[0]);
```

for your scenario.

**NOTE**: I'm assuming that you only have one element on each of the nodes (i.e. `node0`, `node1` and `node2` are arrays but they only have one element)

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pwjNY/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Your solution works fine as long there are no redundant child nodes. If thre is a redundant child node, this adds the child to a new node instead of just ignoring it (It should basically ignore this node since its already present under another parent)...

Comment: But, did you get the idea or do you need help for solving this particular case? Is the answer a solution or need further refining?

Comment: Yep I got an idea but I am still confused how to append children to existing parent if that particular children's parent exist already...

Comment: Hope fixed redundant nodes case. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pwjNY/2/). Just a slight modification in `merge` function.